# Is there a mechanism to upgrade/create database on a Ubuntu .deb package?

Tags: sql, linux, ubuntu, deployment, deb

For example, android platform has something like:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE ....");
    db.execSQL("ATER TABLE ....");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Which is very good to handle upgrades, etc.

Is there a similar strategy for .deb packages? I know I can use the debian/control, debian/preinst to get current version, debian/postinst to handle then the database upgrade, but it's not as neat of a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, there isn't. It doesn't need to be much less clean, though. Your postinst just needs to have something like

```bsh
case "$1" in
    configure)
        oldver=$2
        if dpkg --compare-versions "$oldver" -lt 1.2.3; then
            sqlite3 mydb.db 'DROP TABLE W...'
            sqlite3 mydb.db 'ALTER TABLE X...'
        fi
        if dpkg --compare-versions "$oldver" -lt 1.3.4; then
            sqlite3 mydb.db 'DROP TABLE Y...'
            sqlite3 mydb.db 'ALTER TABLE Z...'
        fi
    ;;
...
esac
```

Comment: And I'd assume "$oldver" is an environment variable you create on preinst, for example?

Comment: No, $oldver is supplied by dpkg as $2. It's assigned on the third line. On first install, it will be empty.

Comment: I hadn't noticed oldver=$2. Thanks a bunch, you nailed my question. I thought I had to do pretty much everything manually like retrieving the current version before installing (preinst), so on and so forth.

Comment: Sorry, but hijacking my own question with another question, but any way to get the current version on a similar way? And where can I find user friendly complete documentation as the man page is a lot verbose and I couldn't find no reference to the parameters you've posted?

Comment: Nope. There's no good way to get the current version from a `postinst configure` run. There are hackish ways that will "usually" work, but don't use those. The expectation is that your code already knows what version it is. The best solution depends on exactly why you want that- I'd recommend starting a new question and explaining the situation.

Comment: Oh, and as far as documentation: I refer to http://people.debian.org/~srivasta/MaintainerScripts.html and http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html very frequently.